# stuck with understanding 2 for loops

Tags: java, perl

i am using this site as a resource
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=573138

I am trying to understand about O notation and it gives two examples of searching two arrays for the same element. First example has O(n^2) as does the second, however the second has an enhancement to it so it runs quicker but still maintains the same O notation, I will paste the code samples below. What I would like to know is how they work, I have limited programming knowledge and am most comfortable in java, i can understand the first I think, just two for loops and check, something like;

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrarysize ; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < arraysize; j++){
        if(getElementFromArray(i).equals(getElementFromArray(j))){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

but how the second works is beyond me, i just don't get the "enhancement"

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
    for my $j (0 .. $#array) {
        next if $j == $i;
        # Compare $i, $j
    }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#array - 1) {
    for my $j ($i + 1 .. $#array) {
        # Compare $i, $j
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged 'java' if your resource is PerlMonks and the code is Perl?

Comment: How about tagging this question with perl too, since it is obviously perl you're dealing with.

Comment: because i didnt no what language it was in and was hoping for a conversion in to java, i have never seen this programming language before, sorry for the confusion

Comment: the if in your java example is wrong. you are only checking the indices, while you should check the values in the array themselves. The perl example does do it correctly though.

Comment: He's asking for a general purpose loop optimization presented in Perl to be translated to Java so that he could possibly understand it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it in terms of a rectangle of possible `(i, j)` values. The first loop compares *every* pair - so it compares (5, 0) and later compares (0, 5) which will obviously just give the opposite result.

The second loop divides that rectangle in half - basically it only checks one "triangle" of it - every value where `j > i` so it would check (0, 5) but not (5, 0). This avoids redundancy - but it just means that it's checking `n*(n-1)/2` values instead of `n^2` values - it's still `O(n^2)`.

The second loop in Java would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraysize - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arraysize; j++){
        if(i == j) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the if in the loop is weird. I would expect one to compare against the value IN the array, and not the indexvalues

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but `i == j` can't be the right test in this context, it would always yield `false`...

Comment: ah.....I see now....you copied the example given by the question asker. It's clear that there too a fault is made. The perl example is obviously correct.

Comment: is there maybe another, more simple example for enhancement - where it maintains the same o notation you could provide? if not then never mind, 

thanks everyone

Comment: What do you mean by "where it maintains the same o notation"? Trying to find duplicate elements in an array is possibly best done with a hash, but that's a somewhat different approach...

Comment: well - i am trying to find limitations of o notations, i was wondering if there was a simple example, ie) not with coordniates that demonstrates an enahncement to a task, where version 1 is the same o notation as version 2, yet version 2 works more efficiently

Comment: That's fairly common. Asymptotic notation hides constants. Rob Pike wrote, “Fancy algorithms are slow when n is small, and n is usually small. Fancy algorithms have big constants. Until you know that n is frequently going to be big, don't get fancy.  (Even if n does get big, use Rule 2 first.)   For example, binary trees are always faster than splay trees for workaday problems.” http://www.quut.com/c/pikestyle.html